why do I need Cupertino
I am reading Chapter 6 of the Flutter Cookbook - Second Edition by Simone Alessandria. The author provides a code recognising the platform and chooses whether to use Cupertino or Material to show a platform-specific dialogue box.

Why does Material not recognise the platform and use Cupertino automatically if it is on iOS? It looks like I have almost to write the same code twice. Or do I miss anything?
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart'; // Imports the Cupertino widgets library for iOS-specific design
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; // Imports the Material widgets library for Android-specific design:



// Class definition for PlatformAlert
class PlatformAlert {
  final String title; // Title of the alert dialog
  final String message; // Message of the alert dialog
  const PlatformAlert(
      {required this.title,
      required this.message}); // Constructor to initialize title and message

  // Method to show the alert dialog based on the platform (iOS or Android)
  void show(BuildContext context) {
    final platform =
        Theme.of(context).platform; // Get the current platform (iOS or Android)
    if (platform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      _buildCupertinoAlert(context); // Show Cupertino (iOS) alert dialog
    } else {
      _buildMaterialAlert(context); // Show Material (Android) alert dialog
    }
  }

  // Private method to build and show a Material (Android) alert dialog
  void _buildMaterialAlert(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(title), // Title of the alert dialog
          content: Text(message), // Message of the alert dialog
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Close'), // Close button
              onPressed: () =>
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(), // Close the dialog when pressed
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  // Private method to build and show a Cupertino (iOS) alert dialog
  void _buildCupertinoAlert(BuildContext context) {
    showCupertinoDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return CupertinoAlertDialog(
          title: Text(title), // Title of the alert dialog
          content: Text(message), // Message of the alert dialog
          actions: [
            CupertinoButton(
              child: const Text('Close'), // Close button
              onPressed: () =>
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(), // Close the dialog when pressed
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

The full code can be found on the author's GitHub

There was a package that's been on pub for a long time where you ask for a "date picker" and it did the right kind depending on platform

No, You don't need to have 2 versions of code for every OS.
Because there's an adaptive dialog, which will be either a material dialog or a cupertino dialog based on the platform in which it's running on.

Displays either a Material or Cupertino dialog depending on platform.
On most platforms this function will act the same as showDialog,
except for iOS and macOS, in which case it will act the same as
showCupertinoDialog.

  showAdaptiveDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context){
        return AlertDialog.adaptive(
        title: Text('Title'),
        content: Text('Any alert message'),
      );
    }
  );
      

for more info showAdaptiveDialog

Thank you, are there any other adaptive alternatives for other widgets? Why showCupertinoDialog and showDialog still exist? It appears that showAdaptiveDialog is more convenient.

@user3523406 they should still exist, and we should pick from according to the desired UI or need, for example web or when your app will run on specific platform, for the other adaptive widgets i'm not sure is there or not.
